# Gem for surveys with images on RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, survey

I am a newbie on RoR and I am looking for a GEM that would create surveys and support images. I have tried Surveyor and it seems great for text only surveys (I will definitely use it again for surveys). Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to generate the HTML with that gem, then use the generated HTML and put it in the `html.erb` and update it with the images.

You can look at the generated HTML with developer tools on your browser.

Otherwise, you will have to write it yourself or add new methods to that gem.